# Rails 4 - ensure has_many associated objects (integer) start at 0 and have no "gap" in the incremental values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have two models sharing a has many/belong to relations

A Deal has_many Steps.

Each step as an attribute called "Appearance Order" which define when it appears (different than the id).

It's an integer that I validate is >= 0 and <15

I input the Steps directly in Active Admin's Deal edition thanks to:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps, allow_destroy: true
```

I already have in place a validation that ensures that there can't be one Step belonging to the same Deal and sharing the similar 'Appearance Order' thanks to:

```
validates :appearance_order, uniqueness: { scope: [:deal_id] }
```

But today, A Deal where the various associated Steps would have as 'Appearance Order" 1, 5, 7,14 would be accepted. **I need to find a validation that reject that case**.

On the Deal model I need validations that ensure:

- among one deal(id:4).steps (steps associated with the Deal) , there is at least one with the 'Appearance Order' equal to 0
- then the deal(id:4).steps' 'Appearance order' have no "gap" between each of their value. It must be 0,1,2,3,4,....and so on.

For example if I create a Deal with 4 Steps who have 'Appearance Order' attribute of 0,1,2,5 should be rejected because there is a gap between 2 and 5.

Here is my code:

**models/step.rb**

```
class Step < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal,             :foreign_key => 'deale_id'
   validates :appearance_order,
              presence: true,
              numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0,
                              less_than_or_equal_to: 14}

   validates :appearance_order, uniqueness: { scope: [:deal_id] }
end
```

**models/deal.rb**

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many   :steps,          dependent:  :destroy do   
    # source: homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/
    def length
      reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).length
    end
  end 

  validates :steps, length: { maximum: 15 }

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about checking the things that you need to check:

```
validate :appearence_order_gaps

private

def appearence_order_gaps
  previous_step = deal.steps.last
  if previous_step
    (previous_step.appearance_order - appearence_order) == 1
  else
    appearence_order.zero?
  end
end
```

So if there is previous step then its appearence_order should be minus one, otherwise current step appearence_order should eq to zero.

Comment: I'll try but will it work as when I input on Active Admin a Deal, it can have many/multiple Steps so how will each "step" already have a "previous" one as they're not yet in the database...sorry newbie here. I'll try and adjust if necessary

Comment: in the line (previous_step.appearance_order - appearence_order) == 1, what is the second appearence_order. It should be deal.steps.current.appearence_order or deal.steps.XXXX.appearence_order,. If not, how does it fetch the deal.Step..?

Comment: second appearance_order is attr of newly step that we're creating. equal to self.appearance_order